# Burning shapefile geometry to raster in PNG format with gdal_rasterize?

Tags: raster, shapefile, gdal, overlay, png

I was trying to overlay a shapefile to some raster images from a directory using `gdal_rasterize`. But then encountered this error:

> ERROR 6: The PNG driver does not support update access to existing datasets.

`input_path` has the raster images and the `shp_path` has the shapefile. Any ideas?

```
@echo off

set "inpath=C:\path\to\input\"
set "shppath=C:\path\to\shape\file\"


cd /d "%inpath%"

for %%a in (*.png) do (
   set "fileName=%%a"
   echo Overlaying the shape file . . .
   FORFILES /m %%a /C "cmd /c gdal_rasterize -b 1 -b 2 -b 3 -burn 0 -burn 0 -burn 0 %shppath%\shpfile.shp %in_path%\@fname.png"

)
```

Comment: you will need to use a different driver that supports update access, such as GTiff (`.tif`)

Comment: But what if the input and output file should be in png not in GTiff(.tif)? Is there any other option? Or just set another output path so that the files will not need any update.

Comment: Convert the .png to .tif for gdal_rasterize, then back to .png at the end. You can use gdal_translate for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

The error message means you can't overwrite (update) an existing raster file of format `.png` with [gdal_rasterize](https://www.gdal.org/gdal_rasterize.html), which is what the tool does by default when the raster file already exists. See the relevant excerpt in `gdal_rasterize` description:

> ... . The target raster will be overwritten if it already exists ... .

The `dst_filename` parameter states that the output file *must support update mode access* which the error message is saying `.png` does not.

The work around is what @Mike T [commented](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/138535/error-6-the-png-driver-does-not-support-update-access-to-existing-datasets#comment200703_138535), use `gdal_translate` to convert your rasters to `.tif`, and then, use the `.tif` files together with parameter `-of` with `gdal_rasterize` to output to a `.png` format.